How to Debug Across PInvoke Layer in .NET MAUI for Android and iOS
I am developing a cross-platform app using .NET MAUI, where the Android version integrates multiple custom .so libraries via PInvoke. These libraries are written in C++ and compiled using the "C++ Android development tools" workload. I then include these libraries in the .NET MAUI project using the <AndroidLibrary .../> tag.
I have full control over both the .NET and C++ codebases. My challenge is establishing a seamless debugging experience that allows me to step through the .NET MAUI code into the C++ code across the PInvoke boundary.
Is there a way to configure the debugger in such a way that it can seamlessly transition between the .NET MAUI code and the native C++ code during a debugging session? If so, what steps should I take to set this up for both Android and iOS?
What I have done already and expected:
Created a binding project using PInvoke. Imported the .so files separately. During debugging, I tried to step into the PInvoke method stub but nothing happened. I have disabled Just My Code and enabled Native/Mixed debugging.

You will have to reveal the IDE you are using, as VS/VS Code/Rider are using different debuggers and don't work the same way.

Certainly @LexLi! I am currently using Visual Studio 2022. However, if needed I am certainly willing to switch IDE to be able to debug it.

It can't be seamless, managed code and native C++ require different debug engines.  You get the debugger to switch between engines by setting a breakpoint.  So set a breakpoint on the C++ function.  The [LibraryImport] attribute is worth noting, as an alternative to [DllImport], that makes the stub code visible to the debugger.

Thanks for the reply @HansPassant. How would I acquire a breakpoint inside my C++ code? As of now, the C++ code is compiled into .so files inside its own Visual Studio project and I would imagine that the debugging can only happen using the compiled .so file and not using this VS project. Do you know of any good resources for this?

What about using AndroidNativeLibrary and mixed debugger?
